# My computer hibernate each 10 seconds

Tags: suspend, dell, hibernate

I have a series problem because **my laptop hibernate every 10 seconds** when I start with ubuntu or kubuntu, since the moment that kubuntu start and never spot. but when I change the HDD with windows I dont have any problem. even when I star with live kubuntu the same thing happened my lap tp is dell latitude e6420. can anybody help me.